# Making Apache to log %D inside quotes

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have this log from Apache server:

```
<134>Nov  18 10:44:44 webserverprd02 apache_access_log: 78.110.27.65 - casinoportugal [18/Nov/2017:10:44:42 +0000] 124703 "POST /netent/walletserver/players/27809/account/deposit HTTP/1.1" 200 118 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6.redhat-3 (java 1.5)"'
```

The value `124703` represents `%D` (The time taken to serve the request, in microseconds). I want to know if it possible to program the log to put the value of `%D` inside `""` (`"124703"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simply to enclose `%D` within double quotes `"%D"`, but the trick is that you need to escape the quotes within the string `LogFormat` option:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%D\" \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```